# C# Windows Forms: SqlConnection keyword not supported, connection timeout

Tags: c#, database-connection, connection-string, sqlconnection

Just learning how to create an Windows Forms application via Tom Owsiak C# Windows Forms video tutorials and I'm stuck at the database project (contacts management system) which requires to store data to a database.

I've been following his every single step yet somehow manage to mess up the application writing process. The error happen at the line

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
```

Have been searching stackExchange for a while now and try possible solution but still couldn't work it out.

```
// error occurs here, stated key word not supported, connection timeout
using (SqlConnection connectforfucksake = new SqlConnection(connString)) 
{
    try
    {
        connectforfucksake.Open(); // open the connection

        // create the new SqlCommand object
        command = new SqlCommand(insert, connectforfucksake); 

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Data_Added", dateTimePicker1.Value.Date);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Company", txtCompany.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Website", txtWebsite.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Title", txtTitle.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"First_Name", txtFName.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Last_Name", txtLName.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Address", txtAddress.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"City", txtCity.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"State", txtState.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Postal_Code", txtPostalCode.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Mobile", txtMobile.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Note", txtNote.Text);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();   // pushing whatever in the form into table
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); // show the unforeseen error
    }
}
```

Expected application to take result and then store them into database but it seem like the `SqlConnection` object instantiate is causing the error.

Comment: From "SqlConnection keyword not supported, connection timeout" - it sounds like the problem **is the connection string**; can you show what you have as the connection string, minus anything like passwords / ip addresses / etc that we **really** don't want/need to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your connection string is simply wrong; most likely, you meant "Connect Timeout" rather than "connection timeout". A basic connection string that includes a connect timeout might be something like:

```
Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=42
```

Comment: The data source goes like this: string connString = @"Data Source=userPc\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AddressBook;Integrated Security=True;Connect
             Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";

Comment: @wingofmessiah ok; and did the exception message **really really** say "key word not supported, connection timeout"? if not, can we have the **exact actual** exception message? But: have you tried simply not including a connect timeout, if SQLEXPRESS doesn't want it? There's a lot of stuff there that isn't needed and you could leave as default - probably everything after Integrated Security

Comment: My bad, this is what the exception show: System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'connect timeout'.'

Comment: @wingofmessiah great; so: remove the `Connect Timeout=30;` from the connection string and see what happens; SQLExpress is a subset of SQL Server and works very differently re where it is hosted - it wouldn't be a huge surprise if some of the pieces work slightly differently

Comment: Holy pepperoni, it worked and there's a upvote for ya, code wizard :D